# Java function refuses to take parameters

Tags: java, class, pointers, constructor

In the following code, an integer is sent to a constructor to be returned. The problem is, when a value is set as a parameter in the constructor, it refuses to compile and outputs that no parameters are needed.

```
class test3 extends Value {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Value var = new Value(3);
   System.out.println(var);
   }
}
class Value {
   public int Value(int num) {
   return num;
   }
}
```

When there are no parameters sent, it compiles and outputs a pointer value.

```
Value@15db9742
```

What am I doing wrong here (I have tried using public classes but it doesn't work)?

Comment: What do you think should be output and why?

Comment: You use the wrong syntax for a constructor.

Comment: A constructor shouldn't be `static` nor should it return any kind of value.

Comment: How am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: If you want to delete the question, just delete it, don't deface it.

Comment: I can't delete it. Stack overflow won't let me.

Comment: Then there is a reason for that.  Defacing the question is still not appropriate.

Comment: And reverted your edit again; Again; don't deface your posts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors use the form `visibility classname(params)`. In your case, this would be:

```
public Value(int num) {...}
```

`static` does not make sense because you are talking about an instance of the class, `int` does not make sense because a constructor does not return anything (it implicitly returns the created object).

Answer (score 3):

Constructors in Java always have the form:

```
{visability} {ClassName}(/* arguments */) {/* body */};
```

Note the lack of return type. Constructors do not return anything explisitly. So in your case it should be:

```
public Value(int num) { /* do something with num */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) are named the same name as the class they're in, but they never have a return type (not even `void`), and they cannot be `static`.  If they have either of these, then they are interpreted as a normal method.  Then Java supplies the default no-arg constructor, which is why you can send no parameters in the constructor and have it compile.

1. Remove `static` and `int`.

   ```
   public Value(int num) {
   ```

Your class doesn't override [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), which is responsible for the `Value@15db9742` output you see.  You will need to override it to supply the text that will eventually be outputted when you pass it to `System.out.println`.  To do this with any meaning:

2. Store the value in an instance variable inside the class.

   ```
   private int num;
   public Value(int num) {
       this.num = num;
   }
   ```
3. Then refer to the instance variable in `toString()`.

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return String.valueOf(num);
   }
   ```

Additionally, your `test3` class shouldn't extend `Value`; a `test3` isn't a `Value`.